# Detect Windows Phone 8 in browser

Tags: html, internet-explorer, user-agent, windows-phone-8

[This link](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/10/17/getting-websites-ready-for-internet-explorer-10-on-windows-phone-8.aspx) claims that Windows Phone 8 devices will get a unique user agent string that specifies both "Windows Phone 8" and "MSIE 10.0". However in my tests of two production WP8 devices (Nokia Lumia 920 and an HTC 8x) both continue to report IE 9 and Windows Phone OS 7.5.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Edit: A friend suggested that this might have to do with incorrect doc-types on the html page, but that doesn't make sense to me since I'm detecting this user agent in the OnActionExecuting event in an ASP.net MVC site (I haven't returned a doctype to the user at this point).

Edit 2: This website will be running inside a webbrowser control in a Xaml application, instead of natively in a browser, should that make any difference.

Comment: User agent sniffing is nearly always the wrong approach. google for "responsive design".

Comment: As @RimuAtkinson pointed out, you're asking the wrong question. Don't *detect browsers*, but rather serve up pages that can accommodate nearly any browser in use by using responsive techniques and feature-detection.

Comment: I am asking the specifically the right question for my situation, but I understand and appreciate your concern.

Comment: The knee-jerk reactions to the User Agent detection questions on Stack Overflow are very annoying. 

Yes, if you are trying to support or accommodate certain features or detect a lack of features, then yes UA detection is the wrong approach.

However, there are several valid instances where you would need to serve up strictly OS specific contextual info or actions where feature detection would be a frustratingly round-about way of doing things. In these cases, AU detection is the best way to figure out if a user is on a certain OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My code was executing inside a WP7 XAML application and the WebBrowser control. You have to upgrade your app to WP8 if you want to get the updated browser in your app.

Answer (score 1):

I can not meet your problem.
my htc 8x's ua is :
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows Phone 8.0; Trident/6.0; IEMobile/10.0; ARM; Touch; HTC;Windows Phone 8X by HTC)

this website can detect your useragent.
http://whatsmyuseragent.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
function isIEMobile() {
    var regExp = new RegExp("IEMobile", "i");
    return navigator.userAgent.match(regExp);
}
```